# Data from server to client in NodeJS express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, post

I am new to NodeJS.
I want to perform a task where, HTML submit button POST data to server
below is the HTML code,

```
<form action="/Device_Data" method="post">
  <select name="deviceSelect" id="deviceSelect" class="selectdevice" type = "text" style="margin-top:1.5%">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Device</option>
    <option value="Device1">Device 1</option>
    <option value="Device2">Device 2</option>
    <option value="Device3">Device 3</option>
    <option value="Device4">Device 4</option>
    <option value="Device5">Device 5</option>
    <option value="Device6">Device 6</option>
    <option value="Device7">Device 7</option>
    <option value="Device8">Device 8</option>
  </select>
  <button id="Import" value="Import" class="button1" type="submit" >Import</button>
</form>
```

Server received the Data in req.body.

```
app.post("/Device_Data", function (req, res) {      
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

  // result.entries contains entities matching the query
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  //console.log(req.body.deviceSelect);

  var deviceSelected = (req.body.deviceSelect);
  console.log(deviceSelected);

  var devData = ["deviceId","trainId", "messageId"];

  //var devData = [];
  var text = JSON.stringify(response.body);
  var obj = JSON.parse(text);
  res.write("Hello");
});
```

Now the part I have question is,
How I can send devData array of string from server to my client and what should be code for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not worked with express for a bit - but I think you could do `res.write(JSON.stringify(devData));` - that would return your devData array as JSON. Is that kinda what you're wanting to do?

Comment: I want that data to be displayed on my webpage, the same webpage from i POST the data.
i am using ajax call as per below,

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Device_Data',
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain:true,
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {

            alert("Data length is " + data.length);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });

Answer (score 1):

According to express documentation, use [res.json](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.json) to send json data as an request answer.

```
res.status(200).json(devData);
```

---

Example from documentation :

```
res.json(null);
res.json({ user: 'tobi' });
res.status(500).json({ error: 'message' });
```

Comment: my AJAX call look like this,

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Device_Data',
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain:true,
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {

            alert("Data length is " + data.length);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });

Comment: `error: function (err) { console.log(err); } })` display the error

Comment: Well, do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(err));`

Comment: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"Internal Server Error\n","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}

now showing